# Flutter : Refresh The Page with AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a card game and it includes 2 parts.

1. InputPage
2. GamePage

In `InputPage()` user picks cards and it has a new game button. When user click on it, page must be reload. I did this with `Navigator.of` method. But when user go to GamePage(), i got an error like this:

```
    Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _GamePageState#d4518(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
```

This is my code:

```
    ayarAlert2(BuildContext context) async {
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            ),
        child: Text(
          "  Settings ",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1F010B),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
    content: Container(
      child: Wrap(
        runSpacing: 5,
        spacing: 10,
        children: <Widget>[
          
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => InputPage()));
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Row(
                  children: [Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "  New Game  ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 32,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.01),
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

When user picks all the cards ,he/she press the " START " button. Heres the start button :

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                  new GamePage(
                                                    mycards: cardBrain.mycards,
                                                    yourcards:
                                                        cardBrain.rakipcards,
                                                    annen: true,
                                                  )));
```

This is InputPage() 's initState

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                content: Container(
                  child: Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  cardBrain.kartbol();
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                });
                              },
                              child: Center(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Center(
                                      child: Container(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "  START  ",
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    // animationController.dispose() instead of your controller.dispose
  }
```

And this is GamePage() 's initState :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => showAlertDialog(context));
    _now = DateTime.now().second.toString();

    // defines a timer
    _everySecond = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      if (annenn == true) {
        setState(() {
          _now = DateTime.now().second.toString();

          if (cardBrain.bitir == 13) {
            if (ihale <= cardBrain.bizimskor) {
              mesaj = "WIN";
            } else {
              mesaj = "LOSE";
            }

            sonucAlert(context, cardBrain.bizimskor, mesaj, cardBrain.onunskor,
                widget.annen);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Always remember to `await` Navigator calls. Change your `onPressed` to `async` and await for navigation

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: My first comment was only an advice because your navigation code was wrong. Anyway the error is clear, you are trying to change state of a disposed Widget. Please provide your full code.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the `popAndPushNamed` method:

```
await Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/gameScreen');
```

Remember to define the route in the `MaterialApp` class, usually in the `main.dart` file:

```
MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => InputPage(),
    '/gameScreen': (context) => GamePage(),
  },
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. When i go to the next page and click something it returns InputPage() again. I am very confused.

Comment: Are you getting another error from the `setState() after dispose`?

Comment: Yes. I get error on second page ( GamePage() ). I'am editing my code right now